# How to pull this 'var static_token'?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pull `static_token`, but I am definitely not on the right track. I pulled all the info that is javascript and my next step I figured was i needed to read it with JSON or turn it into JSON format as this is what i was told on my previous question. I tried to use regex to pull this as well, no luck on that end either, as pointed out in the comments I don't know what I'm doing. Can you point me in the right direction to pull the `static_token` and a brief description of what I need to actually do in these instances?

CODE

```
import requests
import json, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='''  '''
response = requests.get(url)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
html1 = soup1.find_all('script')[1]     #.text
print(html1)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(b'html1', 'lxml')
var = soup2.get('var static_token')
print(var)
```

My attempt with using regex -

```
static_token = re.findall(('static_token":"([^"]+)'), soup.text)
print(static_token)
```

Source I'm trying to pull the info

```
<script type="text/javascript">var CUSTOMIZE_TEXTFIELD = 1;
var FancyboxI18nClose = 'Close';
var FancyboxI18nNext = 'Next';
var FancyboxI18nPrev = 'Previous';
var contentOnly = false;
var roundMode = 2;
var static_token = '850424cb3feab732e072a3d84e378908';
var taxEnabled = 1;
var titleDelivery = '<h3 class="page-subheading">Your delivery address</h3>';
var titleInvoice = '<h3 class="page-subheading">Your billing address</h3>';
var token = '0c7a8347a263972696d6514dcfa24741';
var txtConditionsIsNotNeeded = 'You do not need to accept the Terms of Service for this order.';
var txtDeliveryAddress = 'Delivery address';
var txtErrors = 'Error(s)';
var txtFree = 'Free';
var txtThereis = 'There is';
var txtWithTax = '(tax incl.)';
var txtWithoutTax = '(tax excl.)';
var usingSecureMode = true;
var vat_management = 0;</script>
```

Comment: Aside from the obvious, that *as the error message tells you* you're trying to parse a BS ResultSet as if it was something like a string (...it is not), you're trying to parse something that isn't JSON as JSON.

Comment: thanks for down voting jonsharpe I am only doing this because people on here told me i needed to. why not help point me in the actual right direction?

Comment: Well you're sort of starting right, getting all of the scripts in the document, but your next bit of code makes no sense. Read up on the BS docs, so you know what the method you're calling returns (or just print it and have a look) and what JSON actually is (it's not just *"any JavaScript"*).

Comment: Show us your BeautifulSoup + regex attempt.  That's a much better route.

Comment: static_token = re.findall(('static_token":"([^"]+)'), response.text)
print(static_token)                                                                this is basically what i was trying to use, I added it to the question above and had a couple variations i tried. Thank you for helping me have a better question and not just down voting me.

Comment: Please give an actual [mcve]. And why did you think `static_token = '...` would ever be matched by `static_token":"...`? Do they seem the same? You seem to be writing the regex for JSON, which you **do not have**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing a lot of data types in this question.  This is not the only way to approach this (or the most robust) but it is simple and can point you in the right direction.

You seem to be able to read the html and extract the script tags from it using BeautifulSoup into `html1`.

You need to look at the documentation to understand the data types being used.  I would also recommend adding statements like this in your code to help.

```
html1 = soup.find_all('script')
print('html1', type(html1), html1)  # the type is bs4.element.ResultSet
```

This var contains all of the script tags from your document.  You can iterate over the tags, and find the text fields for each tag.  But it is NOT a JSON formatted type.

Once you have a string and you want part of that string - regex should be one of your first thoughts.  You don't want to use regex on the original html - that's the whole point of the BS4 library and others like it.  HTML is often mangled, messy, and not well-suited for simple regular expressions.  Use BeautifulSoup to parse the html and find the section you want, THEN use regex to parse the string.

```
for tag in html1:
    print('tag', type(tag), tag)  # bs4.element.Tag
    print()

    print('tag.text', type(tag.text), tag.text)  # str
    print()

    toks = re.findall("var static_token =\s*'(\w+)'", tag.text)
    print('toks', type(toks), toks)  # list
    print()

    static_token = toks[0]
    print('static_token', type(static_token), static_token)  # str
    print()
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate the time you put into this answer and appreciate the most you giving me a description of the process.